# Painting exterior caulk

Tags: windows, caulk

The caulk on the exterior of my fiberglass windows turned black after a couple of years and I was never able to get it white again even though I tried every idea I could find online.  Now new vinyl siding has gone on the house and the exterior window frames have been covered with new vinyl and caulked at the seams on the jams and sills.  My question is, should I paint this caulk to try to keep it white?  My house is in a very shady area but even windows that got a lot of sun had this problem.

Comment: Do you know exactly what caulk was used? Some are paintable/ some aren’t. Some mold up more than others.

Comment: Scrub it down with some denatured alcohol so that paint can adhere to it regardless of caulk type and paint it with a high-quality exterior latex paint.